# How do 3D arrays work?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 3d

I've used 2D arrays and I just view them as tables, I'm wondering as to how a 3D array works and how or when you would implement it into a program? Just curious. I should mention I'm using java.

Comment: `String[][][] blah = new String[10][][];` Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Craig Yes, you are missing the 2nd and 3rd dimensions size

Comment: N-dimensional array is a simple array of objects where each object is an (N-1)-dimensional array

Comment: @GermannArlington - The 2nd and 3rd dimension sizes do not need to be specified in Java.

Comment: @GermannArlington `String[][][] blah  = new String[10][][]; blah[0] = new String[3][]; blah[0][0] = new String[2]; blah[0][0][0] = "Hello World";` The size of the other dimensions can set later (jagged arrays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will help to conceptualize it:

1. Index of elements in a row
2. Row and Column of item in a table
3. Layer, Row and Column in a cube
4. Index of element in a row of cubes
5. Row and Column of item in a table of cubes

[image]

This is only if you exist in 3 spatial dimensions; [Live long our 4th dimensional overlords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract), they can go one step further without using cubes of cubes

Comment: Great reference on the Tesseract!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "in a cube"? For example in the 3D array, lets say you have......... `int[][][] = new int[10][4][4];`     Isn't that like just having 10 4x4 tables? Or am I getting this all wrong?

Comment: @OscarF This was meant to be a general explanation of a way you conceptualize multi-dimensional arrays. A _more_ correct term would be [Cuboid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid), however this isn't the whole story as it doesn't take into account jagged arrays in which no polygon would suffice as a analogue.

Comment: @OscarF To answer your comment directly, thinking of it in terms of "10 4x4 tables" is a perfectly valid way of picturing the scenario. Then to go the next step `new int[10][10][4][4]` would represent a 10x10 table where each "cell" in the table is a 4x4 table. Unfortunately (like my initial answer), this cheats you of being able to think about jagged arrays in the same fashion